# OPENROWSET cannot find files with special characters in file name

Tags: sql-server, special-characters, filenames, openrowset

I have to import documents as a whole into an SQL Server table. I have a table with all filenames. I loop through the table and use the following dynamic SQL to load the data.

```
SET @sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE [targettable] SET [ScanData]=(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N''' + @sourcePath + @filename + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) f) WHERE [FileName]=''' + @fileName + '''';
EXEC (@sqlUpdate);
```

This works for most files. But when files have special characters (like "ä" or "š") in their name, then I get a file not found error.

Is there some setting to get OPENROWSET to import those files too? Or is there another way to get the files into a table?

Comment: You tried to add the appropriate `CODEPAGE` to `BULK` ?

Comment: You also need to add a `N` in the `WHERE` clause to denote a Unicode literal: `WHERE [FileName]=N''' + @fileName`. This assumes `@sourcePath` and `@filename` paramaters/variables are declared as `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not OPENROWSET, but the file names themselves. A lot of names had invisible characters. Coincidentally they also had some visible special character, which led me on the wrong trail. After the invisible characters were removed, the statement did work.

Basically the names in my table did not match the names of the files. Special characters and spaces were not the problem.